# wordpress customized theme, default add image in full width

Tags: wordpress

I have written a very basic theme, and want to make sure for every new post, when an image is added, the default attribute would be "width=100%".

any hints please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your individual posts will probably have a class or id on them - if not you need to add one.  For example my site uses this:

```
<div class="post">
    <!-- post content -->
</div>
```

in the CSS for that class then add:

```
.post img
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Note that this is a quick solution giving you exactly what you asked for.  The images probably won't look very good in the posts unless you control your images i.e. only post images that are the same pixel width or larger than the column in which they appear on the site.  Additionally this CSS will target ALL IMAGES in that post, which is fine if your posts are just text and the images you upload.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but when i add a new image, the code would look like this :
<img src="http://link/image.jpg" width="941" height="554" class="aligncenter size-full" />
i.e. it seems the size it detected would override what i did in the CSS file.

Comment: Yes but in wordpress when you select your image in the gallery and add it to the body of your post you can simply delete `class="aligncenter size-full"` - I do this all the time.  If you don't want to delete it then simply use `width: 100% !important;` in the CSS I mentioned above.  That will override the wordpress CSS.

Comment: thank you for your time & detailed explanations, i will give it a try.

Comment: you're right, i found that the post content would simply exists after the tag "<div class="blog-post">", so i just do sth similar to what you suggested in style.css, and now it works flawlessly.  Thank you ~

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this - [content width](https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width)

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i'm very much a newbie in doing wordpress themes, so i found the advice from @garrettlynch to be easier for me to implement, so i  will pick his answer instead.

Comment: sure, no problem :)